# Jquery does not set text box value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set the value of a text box when file upload is selected , how ever it does not happen but I see correct value in alert box.

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="file-label"><i></i>@Resources.FolderPath</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input class=".form-control" name="fileText" type="text" />
            <div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
                <span>Browse</span>
                <input type="file" name="File" id="fileUpload" class="upload"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label id="fileSizeError" style="color: red"></label>
        </div>
    </div>



$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document)
        .on("change","#fileUpload",
            function (e) {
                alert($("#fileUpload").val());
                $("#fileText").val($("#fileUpload").val());
                alert("hi");
            });    

});
```

Please help me here.I am using Asp.net MVC as platform.

Comment: Add an id for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` has a `name`, but `#fileText` is an **ID selector**. Either add an `id` to it, or use an attribute selector to find it.

So either:

```
<input class=".form-control" id="fileText" name="fileText" type="text" />
<!-- add id------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^      -->
```

**or**

```
$("[name=fileText]").val($("#fileUpload").val());
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- use attribute selector
```

Comment: Thanks It worked ! Could not spot that for an hour ! Will accept the answer as soon as Stackoverflow allows me.

Comment: Here's a demo: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/e46d7xmg/) You should remove the dot before form-control in your input class too.

Answer (score -1):

Try native js:

```
document.getElementById("fileText").defaultValue = $("#fileUpload").val();
```

OR

```
$("#fileText").attr("value", "some value");
```

Also;

Check to see if your original code works with replacing `.val()` with `.text`

Comment: *"Try native js"* That's not "native js", it's the DOM API. And it wouldn't help at all with the OP's markup, the above would just throw an error (you're also setting the wrong property; `value` is the one to set, `defaultValue` is just the initial default). *"Check to see if your original code works with replacing `.val()` with `.text`"* Nope. `input `elements don't have text. They do have values.